# Empty WSS_Logging and Can't change to SQL User

Tags: site-usage

I am not getting any information in my usage reports.  My farmadmin user has dbo rights to the logging DB.  Now, I'm trying to set the user under "Configure usage and health data collection" to a SQL user, but it just won't save the user.  No errors, it just won't save the user.  I'm using Sharepoint 2013 standard and everything else seems to be working fine.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.